# Fabric JS Skew Objects Control Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Please guide me how can i fix the issue for Skew issue, i want to set controls properly on the selected objects.
`Refer Link`http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Rq7hk/

Comment: please explain what is the issue

Comment: Check the below link for the same as its working with skew properly but get issue after resize the object 

http://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/89/